# Abstract error when extending classes

Tags: delphi

```
type
  TObjA = class
    a: string;
  end;
type
  worker<T> = interface
    function step1(v: integer): T;
    function step2(s: string): T;
  end;

type
  ImplA<T> = class(TInterfacedObject, worker<T>)
    function step1(v: integer): T;
    function step2(s: string): T; virtual; abstract;
  end;

type
  ImplB = class(ImplA<TObjA>)
    function step2(s: string): TObjA;
  end;
implementation


function ImplA<T>.step1(v: integer): T;
begin
  result := step2(IntToStr(v));
end;

function ImplB.step2(s: string): TObjA;
var
  r: TObjA;
begin
  r := TObjA.Create;
  r.a := 'step2 ' + s;
  result := r;
end;
```

I am trying to build a functionality according to this structure. I know it works in java, but currently I am working in delphi 2010.
I get an abstract error when calling ImplB.step1(1)
How do I fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You get the error as you do not declare `function step2(s: string): TObjA;` as an `override`.

So in

```
function ImplA<T>.step1(v: integer): T;
begin
  result := step2(IntToStr(v));
end;
```

it is calling `step2` from `ImplA` not `ImplB` as you are expecting it to

Your also changing the return type from a generic object to TObjA, the compiler may not like that, but I don't have a copy of Delphi that supports generics to hand to test.

Comment: Thank you, that was it exactly. All I had to do was add the override keyword. :)